# ¿como utilizar concat en un update de laravel, utilizando eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

estoy tratando de actualizar un registro em mi base de datos perdo solo quiero actializar la fecha y dejar la hora intacta, para eso debo usar concat para lograrlo, coloque la consulta completa de mysql pero quiero saber si puedo usar eloquent para lograrlo, creo que seria mas seguro.
mi consulta es asi:

```
$event=  DB::update("update agendas set inicio =concat('".$request->NuevaFecha." ', time(inicio)),
      fin= concat('".$request->NuevaFecha." ', time(fin))
       WHERE iduser='".$request->user."' and inicio BETWEEN '".$fechaInicio."' and '".$fechaFin."'");
```

alguien sabe como podria hacerlo mejor? agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera, debería funcionar pero no puedo testearlo en este momento, en caso que no lo haga me dices y borro la respuesta.

```
Agenda::where('iduser', $request->user)
    ->whereBetween('inicio', array($fechaInicio,$fechaFin))
    ->update([
        'inicio' => DB::raw('CONCAT("'.$request->NuevaFecha.' ",time(inicio))'),
        'fin' => DB::raw('CONCAT("'.$request->NuevaFecha.' ",time(fin))')
    ]);
```

Saludos.

Comment: si me ayudo, aunque hay un error por las comillas que solucione, pero me ayudaste, gracias

Comment: Buenísimo, indícame en que parte esta equivocado así aprovechamos y lo arreglo.

Comment: sucede que al concatenar la fecha que viene en el request y la hora no hay espacio entre ellos y muestra error en el formato 2019-01-2612:00 le hace falta un espacio entre la fecha y hora, pero lo arregle usando las comillas dobles y sencillas